# Extraction failed for file: in ExtractFiles@1

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a react js application, that one currently set for Azure CI/CD pipelines.

Suddenly it started failing at the release phase. it's building successfully and I can see .zip file created in artifacts.

Extract file task set in the [following way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops)

[image]

error occurring this way, no more details about the extraction failing

[image]

> Extraction failed for file:
> /home/vsts/work/r1/a/{pipeline_project}/drop/{build_number}.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExtractFiles](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/pull/16862) task has been migrated from the `Node 10` handler to the `Node 16` handler.

There's a known issue here in the `Node 16` handler compared to the `Node 10` handler. [A Pull Request](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/pull/873) to increase the value of the `maxBuffer` option has been created to fix the issue.

Currently, the task version has been overridden to the previous one (`1.200.0`). Tested it, now it works.

Please try it again using the task version `1.200.0`.